# perl regex put all matches into an array including full match

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following perl code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$key = 'foobar:foo:bar';
$pattern = '^[^:]+:([a-z]{3}):(.+)$';
my @matches = $key =~ /$pattern/i;
print Dumper(@matches);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'foo';
$VAR2 = 'bar';
```

Or alternatively I can `print $1` for first capture group, `$2` for second.

What I want to know is how do I get the full pattern match.  For example in PHP if I used `preg_match`, I would get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foobar:foo:bar
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
)
```

Where the first element (or $0 or \0) is the full match.  How do I get this in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$&` or `${^MATCH}` variables for this, although there is a performance penalty (quite significant for `$&`) in Perl versions before 5.20. From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions):

> - $MATCH
> - $&
>
> The string matched by the last successful pattern match (not counting any matches hidden within a BLOCK or `eval()` enclosed by the current BLOCK).
>
> [...]
>
> - ${^MATCH}
>
> This is similar to `$&` (`$MATCH`) except that it does not incur the performance penalty associated with that variable.
>
> [...]
>
> In Perl v5.18 and earlier, it is only guaranteed to return a defined value when the pattern was compiled or executed with the `/p` modifier. In Perl v5.20, the `/p` modifier does nothing, so `${^MATCH}` does the same thing as `$MATCH`.
>
> This variable was added in Perl v5.10.0.

### Performance issues

Again from [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions):

> Traditionally in Perl, any use of any of the three variables `` $` ``, `$&` or `$'` (or their `use English` equivalents) anywhere in the code, caused all subsequent successful pattern matches to make a copy of the matched string, in case the code might subsequently access one of those variables. This imposed a considerable performance penalty across the whole program, so generally the use of these variables has been discouraged.
>
> [...]
>
> In Perl 5.10.0 the `/p` match operator flag and the `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}`, and `${^POSTMATCH}` variables were introduced, that allowed you to suffer the penalties only on patterns marked with `/p`.
>
> In Perl 5.18.0 onwards, perl started noting the presence of each of the three variables separately, and only copied that part of the string required; so in
>
> ```
> $`; $&; "abcdefgh" =~ /d/
> ```
>
> perl would only copy the "abcd" part of the string. That could make a big difference in something like
>
> ```
> $str = 'x' x 1_000_000;
> $&; # whoops
> $str =~ /x/g # one char copied a million times, not a million chars
> ```
>
> In Perl 5.20.0 a new copy-on-write system was enabled by default, which finally fixes all performance issues with these three variables, and makes them safe to use anywhere.

#### Example:

```
perl -wE 'say for "foo:bar" =~ /^(\w+):(\w+)$/p; say ${^MATCH}'
```

#### Output:

```
foo
bar
foo:bar
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `@-` and `@+` variables, which give the indices of successful matches and don't have the performance hit that `$&` and `${^MATCH}` do, but I think they're a bit cumbersome to use. These are also documented in perlvar.

Answer (score 8):

Begin and end your regular expression with parentheses and make the whole expression another capture group.

```
my @matches = $key =~ /($pattern)/i;

print Dumper( ["foobar:foo:bar"=~/$pattern/i] );
$VAR1 = [
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ];

print Dumper( ["foobar:foo:bar"=~/($pattern)/i] );
$VAR1 = [
      'foobar:foo:bar',
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ];
```